# Why does VSCode not show this three-dot underline indicator I see in the editor in the Problems panel?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

[Screenshot demonstrating the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Donsx.png)

I have two errors in this file, and both are showing up in the Problems panel. All good.

There is a warning too, however, on line 8. It's a warning about the member `dummy` implicitly having an "any" type, and I notice it's not showing up in the Problems panel.

Why is that, and how can I make sure things like this show up in the panel?

I checked the filters for the Problems panel, thinking that maybe the warning was being filtered. The Errors, Warnings, and Infos checkboxes are all enabled though, so that's not the issue.

Here's a smaller repro:

```
class Foo {
  bar; // <- three-dot underline here under the "b" of "bar"
}
let baz; // <- three-dot underline here under the "b" of "baz"
```

Comment: In line 8 it is not an error. They indicate that visual studio has a suggestion. Move the cursor there and press Alt+Enter.

Comment: I see! So it's not coming from TS itself, it's coming from VSCode, suggesting a refactoring.

Comment: it comes from the co-operation of [tsserver](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Standalone-Server-(tsserver)) (part of TypeScript) and [VS Code's TypeScript language support extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/typescript-language-features) using [the VS Code API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api). Both TypeScript problem IntelliSense and TypeScript Quick Fix IntelliSense in VS Code are implemented through that "co-operation" (more like the extension wrapping/using/communicating-with tsserver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because that three-dot underline indicator is not a problem indicator (in the VS Code sense of the word "problem")- it's a Quick Fix indicator. In VS Code, there are three types of problems: Info (blue underline), Warning (yellow underline), and Error (red underline). (The exact colours depend on the colour theme, but usually they are based on those colours). VS Code Quick fixes are not VS Code problems, so they don't show up in VS Code's problems panel.